# The right way to store static file for load-balancing in Laravel App

Tags: laravel, storage, load-balancing, digital-ocean

I have a Laravel app that users can upload images, I am going to use load-balancer in production (2 web servers), so as I understand I have to store static file in separate storage. I use digitalocean droplet for web server and digitalocean space to store images.

The problem I'm facing is web server response is very slow, it take like 5 seconds,because it has to check that file is available in DO space or not for every response.

for example, to get this below response I have to check if logo is exists in the path or not.

```
{
    "_id": "5c18fe1fbfaa6a5ae1141e08",
    "title": "Test Even 2",
    "organization_id": 2,
    "logo": {
        "360": "https://ezpwe.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com/events/5c18fe1fbfaa6a5ae1141e08/logo/360.png",
        "480": "https://ezpwe.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com/events/5c18fe1fbfaa6a5ae1141e08/logo/480.png",
        "720": "https://ezpwe.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com/events/5c18fe1fbfaa6a5ae1141e08/logo/720.png"           
    }
}
```

with this code

```
public function getLogoAttribute($value)
{
    $path = "events/{$this->id}/logo";
    $files = collect(Storage::files($path));

    return $files->isEmpty() ? null : $files->mapWithKeys(function ($file) {
        return [File::name($file) => Storage::url($file)];
    });
}
```

I saw in the [document](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/spaces/resources/performance-tips/) said, it use HTTP to connect DO space and HTTP is so much slower than traditional block storage, It's designed for large files.

What can I do to improve performance, should I use another service?